# Cannot log in to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, authentication

I have problem with my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. I want to log in using windows authentication and server name "local", but error 2 is returned. I've tried to login with a server name of "IP address of my server" but again it failed. Does anybody know what should I do?

Error message:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)*

Comment: What is the error message you receive? Are you sure your windows login has been added to the server?

Comment: yesterday I login to to my database in this way but today i cann't do it

Comment: Can you verify the `SQL Server` service is running?

Comment: Are you sure the service is started?  Might seem dumb, but that's a good place to start.

Comment: Don't forget you can always PING YOURSERVERNAME to check that the server is online.

Comment: Did you search for this error message at all? It's quite common. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that sql server service is running. I,ve checked the tcp/ip protocol and it's enabled.

Comment: If you could do this yesterday but now can't, what was changed on the server?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you TCP/IP is enabled under SQL SErver Network Configuration
[image]

If it is disabled than please enable it and restart services for that instance.

you will be able to log-in.

Comment: This might be the answer but there can be many reasons for the error mentioned by OP. Error simply says SQL Server was not detected by connecting string. If OP is giving incorrect name, Port is blocked, connecting to named instance and Browser service is not up, you can get such messages